# Почему не работают cookie в Apache PHP?

Tags: apache, php, cookie

Подскажите, пожалуйста, настроил `php+apache+mysql` (`apache 2.2.19 win32 x86 openssl-0.9.8r, php php-5.3.6 Win32 VC9-x86`). Вот [настройки](http://narod.ru/disk/20171256001/httpd_%26_php.zip.html). Не работают куки, при выводе массива куков показывает [PHPSESSID]= и здесь пишет id сессии. Как сделать чтобы куки работали (в браузере куки включены)?

Comment: Раз пишет PHPSESSID, значит куки работают.

Comment: Когда делаю `$_COOCIE['здесь значение']="фыв"` или `setcoocie("asd","asd",time()+123)` при выводе `echo $_COOKIE['asd']` он ничего не выводит и при проверке `isset, то она вообще не существует.

Comment: Так вы проверяете куку сразу после установки или при следующем запросе видите, что кука не выставилась?

Comment: правильно тег присать $_COOKIE а не  $_COOCIE, не могу как коммент добавить, не хватает кармы :(

Comment: Так я и пишу `$_COOKIE['asd']=""`, там опечатка и все равно данное значение куки не выводит. Проверяю при следующем запросе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что куки правильно устанавливать функцией [setcookie](http://php.su/functions/?setcookie). И прочитайте внимательно, очобенно то, что устанавливаться они должны до любого вывода, чтоб сервер мог их послать вместе с хедерами.